# Rancher: Unsupported config option for xxx service: 'upgrade_strategy'"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I'm following this [tutorial](http://rancher.com/docker-based-build-pipelines-part-3-managing-production-environments/) I want to use this option for making zero-downtime when upgrading:

```
auth-service:
  upgrade_strategy:
    start_first: true
```

But when I tried to build, I meet following error:

> Unsupported config option for  xxx service: 'upgrade_strategy'"

My rancher compose version is: `v0.12.1-rc2`. Time I upgraded to this version is much later time of above topic so I don't think because compose version issue.

I don't know how to fix this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what I was wrong. This option doesn't put in `docker-compose` but in `rancher-compose.yml` instead.